# Refactor to checking env variables

Tags: ruby

I have this code to check whether the environment variables are empty or not and raise an exception.

```
sample_id       = ENV['SAMPLE_ID']
sample_password  = ENV['SAMPLE_PASSWORD']
raise "ENV variables are empty!" if ENV['SAMPLE_ID'].nil? || ENV['SAMPLE_PASSWORD'].nil?
```

Is there any way to write these code in a more eloquent way? I am using variable `env` two times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
sample_id       = ENV['SAMPLE_ID']
sample_password = ENV['SAMPLE_PASSWORD']

raise 'ENV variables are empty!' unless sample_id && sample_password
```

Answer (score 0):

It all comes to the matter of taste in programming style. In my opinion your code looks ok unless you are using the same code block in different places throughout your application. In that case you should of wrapped it in a class or method to ensure that necessary application parts are set or not.